# How to add brackets (a) to ordered list? compatible in all browsers

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I have to show like

(a)

(b)

(c)

**Update:**

I found a CSS way

```
ol {list-style-type: none;}
li:before {content: "(" counter(section, lower-alpha) ") ";}
li { counter-increment: section;}
```

but it not works in IE 7 and lower.

Comment: Those are parentheses, not brackets. ;)

Comment: Good that you figured it out. Changing the question after the fact is not nice though. This will give IE some more capabilities, but it doesn't include `counter`: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ I think you're mostly out of luck.

Comment: i was also looking on IE7.js but it's not showing support :( for `counters` http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/test/index.html

Comment: @Jimmy - what? "Parentheses" and "brackets" are two words that mean precisely the same thing.

Comment: @Hammerite - Not "precisely the same thing," but upon further investigation, the two might be used interchangeably in the UK: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1636635/1469208) you have a very neat solution, that uses CSS counters.

Answer (score 10):

This is possible with custom counters, but at least IE7- doesn't support it, some others mightn't either. See here for details: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/counter.html

Ex:

```
li:before {
    content: "(" counter(mycounter,lower-latin) ")";
}
```

Comment: but i need on `ol` because it's ordered list

Comment: @jitendra Then you'll need to change the CSS accordingly, this is only an example. I'm just pointing you in the right direction, you'll have to code it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

I use this code snippet in mediawiki with CSS enabled.  I am not sure whether this will work in older versions of IE...

```html
<style>
    /* css handles the parentheses/brackets */
    .laparent ol { counter-reset: item }
    .laparent li { display: block ; counter-increment: item; }
    /* replace the counter before list item with
              open parenthesis + counter + close parenthesis */
    .laparent li:before { content: " (" counter(item,lower-alpha) ") "; }
</style>
<ol class="laparent">
    <li> this is the first item; </li>
    <li> this is the second item; or </li>
    <li> this is the third item. </li>
</ol>
```

Outputs:

```
(a) this is the first item;
(b) this is the second item; or
(c) this is the third item.
```

Comment: You should format your answer and describe what you're doing. It may seem straight forward to you but you could afford a few explaining words

Comment: this puts (a) to the start of the block, not next to it as marker is

Answer (score 2):

Since CSS3 the problem seems solved:

```
style="list-style-type: parenthesized-lower-latin;"
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-lists-20110524/

Comment: This does not seem to be valid anymore

Comment: As mentioned by @wentjun, this is no longer supported.  Unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply add the text count manually without having yo worry about browser fallbacks. Works in any browser!

```css
ul.abc-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
ul.abc-list > li > span.counter {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -20px;
  /*if you want to right align the text
   * 
   * width: 15px;
   * text-align: right;
   */
}
```

```html
<ul class="abc-list">
  <li><span class="counter">a)</span> One</li>
  <li><span class="counter">b)</span> Two</li>
  <li><span class="counter">c)</span> Three</li>
  <li><span class="counter">d)</span> Four</li>
  <li><span class="counter">e)</span> Five</li>
  <ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get (a) (b) (c).

You *can* however get the letter without the brackets:

`<ul style="list-style-type: lower-latin;">...</ul>`

See http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-type_all

Comment: i know how to get letters without bracket. i asked question to know how to add bracket. i think no option :(

Answer (score 0):

[These are your options](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type) according to W3C.

With CSS it isn't possible.  You would have to make a custom list using javascript (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do this.  Which means you enter the land of (fun) hacks.

You could try a background image of two parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I instead made paragraphs.  I indented the paragraph and then pulled out the first line, using a text-indent and numbered these myself.

```
.list_indent {
margin-left:48px;
}
.list_indent p {
text-indent:-26px;
}

<div class="list_indent">  
<p> (1)&nbsp;&nbsp;The recruitment report and a copy of the blah and blah and blah and blah and blah and blah and blah and blah.;
</p>   
<p> (2)&nbsp;&nbsp;A copy of the blah and blah and blah and blah and blah and blah and blah and blah.
</p>     
<p> (3)&nbsp;&nbsp;Recruitment.
</p>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is fixed, a workaround can be :

```
<ul>
  <li style="list-style:symbol('(a)');">...</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li style="list-style:symbol('(b)');">...</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li style="list-style:symbol('(c)');">...</li>
</ul>
...
```

which gives

```
  (a) ...
  (b) ...
  (c) ...
   ...
```

Hope this helps.