# Making list using html for the given output

Tags: css, html

What is the expected code for the given output?

```
1.(a)fruits
     (i)mango
     (ii)apple)
  (b)vegitables.
```

Comment: SO is not a "gimme the code plz" site. Please show your attempts and your efforts.

Comment: same concept with this one: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558358/how-to-add-brackets-a-to-ordered-list-compatible-in-all-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

```
<ol>
<li>
    <ol type='a'>
        <li>fruits
            <ol type='i'>
                <li>mango</li>
                <li>apple</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>vegitables</li>
    </ol>
</li>   
</ol>
```

Please check now

Answer (score 0):

HERE IS THE CODE FOR YOUR OUTPUT... But once google before asking anything.. This is a small thing..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MARKET</title>
</head>

<body>
<ol type="a">
<li> Fruits
<ol type="i">
<li>Mango</li>
<li>Apple</li>
</ol>
</li>
<li>Vegetables</li>       
</ol> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just close watch my question.I want the 1 and (a) as the same line.