# HTML - ordered list, styling the list numbers like (a), (i), (aa)

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-counter

I have attached my HTML and CSS file.

**What I need**: the "a." should be enclosed within () like (a) and the "i" in the next level as (i) and under the "i" the list number shown as "1" should be displayed as (aa) next as (ab) and so on.

I want the alignment to remain as it is and only the styling to change inline with my expectations. How to do this?

**Note: The solution shouldn't cause change in alignment and JavaScript isn't allowed**

```css
p.p1 {
  text-indent: 0cm;
  margin-left: 36;
  word-break: break-all;
}
li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  margin-top: 10pt;
  word-break: break-all;
}
li::before {
  content: "";
  width: 13pt;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ol1 {
  padding-left: 2pt;
}
.pNote {
  text-indent: 0cm;
  margin: 0cm 0cm 10pt;
}
```

```html
<ol class="ol1">
  <li>FirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirst
    <ol type="a">
      <li>Bullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-a
        <ol type="i">
          <li>Bullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-i
          </li>
          <ol type="aa">
            <li>Bullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aa
            </li>
            <li>
              Bullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-ab
            </li>
          </ol>
          <li>
            Bullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-ii
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        Bullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-b
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    SecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecond
  </li>
  <li>
    ThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThird
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I think you need to use counters to get formatted outputs (like (a), (b) etc). There was something in CSS3 spec about list-style-type supporting counter styles but I don't think they are implemented yet (atleast not in all browsers).

Comment: in `ol` (aa),(ab).. will come only after completion of z. i.e, order is like this a,b,c...x,y,z,aa,ab...

Comment: I think the dupe closure is wrong because (a) it doesn't achieve an output similar to what OP wants but that is the smaller point (b) the linked thread has no implementation for (aa), (ab) styles and this is one key point of this question. Hence, I voted to reopen the question (again completely forgetting that a single vote reopens it fully).

Comment: Was the dupe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558358/how-to-add-brackets-a-to-ordered-list-compatible-in-all-browsers

Comment: @mplungjan: No, it was this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859932/style-an-ordered-list-like-1-1-1-2-instead-of-1-2 (and I am not too sure about the one you've linked too because it doesn't handle the (aa), (bb) portion of the question). I am almost about to post an answer explaining how to achieve this but my concern on closure is not just because of that :)

Comment: Im sorry if my above statement dint convey exactly what I need: I have got everything right, now in above thing, what i need is just all the "a." to be made as "(a)" also "i" as "(i)".

Comment: @ManojShenoy: Atleast to me your question was rather clear and I've added an answer also. I hope it helps you. I don't know if you are OK with using CSS `counter` but I couldn't think of a better way to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the styling of list numbers with braces is currently not possible. [There was a section in the CSS3 spec about custom defining counter styles and using it along with `list-style-type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-counter-styles-3/#extending-css2) but it doesn't seem to  be implemented fully yet (atleast not cross-browser) and so your best bet would be to use counters for custom styling the list numbers instead of using the default list style types.

While using counters, we just have to assign one counter for each level, reset/initialize the counter at its corresponding `ol` tag, increment the counter's value whenever a `li` is encountered and display the value of the counter before the text using `:before` pseudo-element. Counter values are displayed using the `content` property of pseudo-elements and hence the braces can easily be added (it is just like doing string concatenation).

For the (aa), (bb) styles, there is defined counter-style-type and like varun aaruru had mentioned in his comment, there is no pre-defined counter/list style for this and such a value comes only after alphabet `z` is reached. In default `ol` styling this could be done giving a start value but it still does not produce the brackets and so we again have to use counters. In counters, we can achieve this by resetting the counter's initial value itself to 26 (z is the 26th alphabet).

The below snippet produces the output that you are looking for.

```css
p.p1 {
  text-indent: 0cm;
  margin-left: 36;
  word-break: break-all;
}
li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  margin-top: 10pt;
  word-break: break-all;
}
li::before {
  content: "";
  width: 13pt;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ol1 {
  padding-left: 2pt;
}
.pNote {
  text-indent: 0cm;
  margin: 0cm 0cm 10pt;
}

/* initialize counters */

ol.a {
  counter-reset: list-item-level2;
}
ol.i {
  counter-reset: list-item-level3;
}
ol.aa {
  counter-reset: list-item-level4 26;
}

/* nullify default list styling */

ol.a li,
ol.i li,
ol.aa li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* reset the word break for pseudo elements */

ol.a li:before,
ol.i li:before,
ol.aa li:before {
  word-break: normal;
}

/* increment the counters */

ol.a li {
  counter-increment: list-item-level2;
}
ol.i li {
  counter-increment: list-item-level3;
}
ol.aa li {
  counter-increment: list-item-level4;
}

/* display the counter values */

ol.a li:before {
  content: '('counter(list-item-level2, lower-latin)')';
  margin-right: 16px;
}
ol.i li:before {
  content: '('counter(list-item-level3, lower-roman)')';
  margin-right: 16px;
}
ol.aa li:before {
  content: '('counter(list-item-level4, lower-latin)')';
  margin-right: 28px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="ol1">
  <li>FirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirstFirst
    <ol class="a">
      <li>Bullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-aBullet-a
        <ol class='i'>
          <li>Bullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-iBullet-i
          </li>
          <ol class="aa">
            <li>Bullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aaBullet-aa
            </li>
            <li>Bullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-abBullet-ab
            </li>
          </ol>
          <li>
            Bullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-iiBullet-ii
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        Bullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-bBullet-b
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    SecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecondSecond
  </li>
  <li>
    ThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThirdThird
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Just for my understanding, is this answer not more or less what [the dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558358/how-to-add-brackets-a-to-ordered-list-compatible-in-all-browsers) has?

Comment: @mplungjan: I don't think so because as I said in comments to the question, it doesn't have handling for the (aa), (bb) types. I added an explanation for the (a), (b) just to make sure the entire answer remains in one place and I can replace that with the link if its thought of as rep-hunting (or) plagiarism.

Comment: Harry, Thanks a lot.
One small changes, in list "(a)" the closing brace is going to new line.
Sorry I have no idea on CSS

Comment: @ManojShenoy: Can you please show that in a demo? Because the snippet output doesn't push it to the next line. Also, try adding `ol.a li:before { word-break: normal; }` (like I have done for the other `ol`s, it will prevent the break).

Comment: @Harry : Run your code here, check line no. 7(including blank line), 7th line has    (a  and 8th line has )     Bullet...., So it is breaking line after "(a", I have least idea, and this im doing for building an .chm

Comment: In Firefox, I can see what you mentioned but it goes away when the code I gave in my 2nd last comment was added. Wait and I'll add it into answer also.

Comment: @Harry one more help, in (a)(b)(c)....(z), I dont want (i) and (o) to come, how to take this off?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100279/discussion-between-manoj-shenoy-and-harry).

Comment: @ManojShenoy: That wouldn't be possible with CSS and even with JS, I don't think it would be possible because currently JS cannot access CSS counter value. The value is visible only to CSS.

Comment: @Harry : I did that skipping (i) `ol.a li:nth-child(9)
{
   counter-reset: list-item-level2 9;
}` added this, Thanks a lot for ur support