# order list not working with ol type="a"

Tags: html, css

I want to show order list as below using class. I have tried but its not working,please help me How I can do it?

```
1. List item
    1.1 list item
       (a) lit item a
       (b) list item b
 2. List item
    2.1 list item
       (a) lit item a
       (b) list item b



.listStyle08 {
    counter-reset: item;
} 
.listStyle08 ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
.listStyle08 li {
    display: block;
}
.listStyle08 li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    counter-increment: item;
    display: inline-block !important;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: What is your HTML markup, and how does the CSS code reflect your attempt at achieving the presentation you describe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somethingkindawierd/rqhK9/) with a working solution.

The styles are copied here for convenience:

```
ol {
    counter-reset: section;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counters(section, ".") ". ";
}

li li:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counters(section, ".") " ";
}

ol ol ol {
    counter-reset: list;
    margin: 0;
}

ol ol ol > li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

ol ol ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: list;
    content: "(" counter(list, lower-alpha) ") ";
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.4em;
}
```

Sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters
- [Ordered list (HTML) lower-alpha with right parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632005/ordered-list-html-lower-alpha-with-right-parentheses)
- http://jsfiddle.net/nKtE6/2/

Comment: i am willing to do this using class,because i am using different type of order list eg. 1.List item 1.1 sub list item (i)sub sub list item,how i can do above solution using class?

Comment: simply prefix the selectors I have with a class name, e.g. replace `ol` with `.listStyle08 ol`

Comment: its not working http://jsfiddle.net/rqhK9/15/

Comment: i am trying but still its not working,can you please guide me?

Comment: Ah. You need to continue counting across multiple lists. I'll have to think about that one, but I'd start by [reading this W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters) to see if we can group the lists under another element to continue the counting across them.