# HTML numbering with brackets

Tags: html

Please how to set up numbering in this format:

```
1) number 1
2) number 2
3) ...
```

in html?

I only found a way to get this format:

```
1. number 1
2. number 2
3. ...
```

No bracket after the number.

Also, is it possible to set up start, kind of numbering, but no other format.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: I think that you don't understand me right. I need something like this.
1) item
2) item

Not only
1 item
2 item

Comment: have you seen this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632005/ordered-list-html-lower-alpha-with-right-parentheses

Comment: This is a nice post on css lists: http://alistapart.com/article/taminglists/

Answer (score 25):

You can achieve this with an ordered list `<ol>`:

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: list;
}
ol > li {
    list-style: none;
}
ol > li:before {
    content: counter(list) ") ";
    counter-increment: list;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some more text</li>
    <li>some further text</li>
</ol>
```

Sample **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qNjSp/)**

Referenced from: [Ordered list (HTML) lower-alpha with right parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632005/ordered-list-html-lower-alpha-with-right-parentheses)

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a little old now, but none of these solutions take into account double-digits or triple-digits or even wrapping lines of text.

```css
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ol {
    counter-reset: list;
}

ol > li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

ol > li:before {
    content: counter(list) ")";
    counter-increment: list;
    left: -40px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li>Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. Line 2 is long. </li>
    <li>Line 3 is not so long.</li>
    <li>Line 4</li>
    <li>Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. Line 5 is long. </li>
    <li>Line 6 is not so long.</li>
    <li>Line 7</li>
    <li>Line 8 is long. Line 8 is long. Line 8 is long. Line 8 is long. Line 8 is long. Line 8 is long. Line 8 is long. Line 8 is long. </li>
    <li>Line 9 is not so long.</li>
    <li>Line 10</li>
    <li>Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. Line 11 is long. </li>
    <li>Line 12 is not so long.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<style>
ol {
columns:2;
}
ol > li::marker {
content:counter(list-item) ")\2003";
}
</style>

<ol>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Darkness</li>
<li>My</li>
<li>Old</li>
<li>Friend</li>
<li>I<br>Have</li>
<li>Come</li>
<li>To</li>
<li>Talk</li>
<li>To</li>
<li>You</li>
<li>Again</li>
</ol>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't currently work on Safari.  [pen](https://codepen.io/kentr/pen/BaLqXQE), [::marker pseudo-element on caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=marker)

Answer (score 4):

Use an **ordered list**:

e.g.

```
<ol>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

A more detailed explanation is available here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

**If you're particularly interested in the parentheses**, you can do it in css with something like this:

```
ol {list-style-type: none;}
li:before {content: counter(section, lower-alpha) ") ";}
li { counter-increment: section;}
```

Note however that this may not work perfectly in IE7 or below.

Comment: As I understand the question, he wants to format his list in a different way.

Comment: I think that you don't understand me right. I need something like this. 1) item 2) item Not only 1 item 2 item

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're looking for now. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

About the closest you can come in HTML without using JavaScript (or other scripting language) is to use the CSS **:before** pseudoelement.

In internal styles:

```
<style>
li:before {
content: ") ";
}
</style>


<ol>
<li>First List Item</li>
</ol>
```

or if just wanting to target a certain class of <li>

```
li.parenthesis:before
```

then in html

```
<li class="parenthesis">First List Item</li>
```

Comment: This will leave numbers with a dot before the parenthesis like following, 1.) , 2.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="counter-increment">
 <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ul>

ul.counter-increment li {
counter-increment: section;
display: table-row;
}

ul.counter-increment li::before {
content: "(" counter(section) ") ";
display: table-cell;
padding-right: 5px;
text-align: left;
}
```