# Custom list style for ordered lists

Tags: css, html-lists

Is it possible to define a style for an ordered list that renders something like

```
<ol>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

as

(1) Item 1

(2) Item 2

(3) Item 3

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Very close to a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632005/ordered-list-html-lower-alpha-with-right-parentheses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `css counter` and `:before` pseudo-element to create this type of list.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: custom;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol li:before {
  content: '('counter(custom)') ';
  counter-increment: custom;
}
```

```html
<ol>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```