# How to create numbered lists in (#) style with Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

The RST documentation quoted by Sphinx as "The authoritative reStructuredText User Documentation" (see [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#restructuredtext-primer)) shows several styles for the formatting of numbered lists, among them the parenthesized style (see [here](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#enumerated-lists)):

```
(1) foo
(2) bla
```

However, Sphinx generates a style with dots from such RST source:

```
1. foo
2. bla
```

The Sphinx documentation only shows that dotted style (see [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#lists-and-quote-like-blocks)).

My question is: Is there any way to make Sphinx create the parenthesized style for the numbers?

Comment: Your first example should work as is. Can you clarify what you actually see?

Comment: @StevePiercy What I see is exactly what is shown in the second example section above, i.e. the dot style. Hence my question.

Comment: Yes, with custom CSS. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1636635/2214933 and an example jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lasomd8t/

Answer (score 7):

```
* This is a bulleted list.
* It has two items, the second
  item uses two lines.

1. This is a numbered list.
2. It has two items too.

#. This is a numbered list.
#. It has two items too.
```

See [reStructuredText Primer](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html?highlight=numbered%20list) in Sphinx documentation site.

Comment: The question is about how to generate a numbered list where the number of each list item is parenthesized. This answer does not show how to do that.

Comment: Good point. I should have read more carefully. According to http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#why-do-enumerated-lists-only-use-numbers-no-letters-or-roman-numerals the output style is handled by the style sheet. This would require adding custom style sheets. See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/adding-custom-css.html.