# Can I add list style type like "a)" to ckeditor?

Tags: html, ckeditor, html-lists

Is there a way to offer a list styling like:

```
a)
b)
c)
```

in version 4 of ckeditor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/1636635/1891840 is explained that you can use CSS to create a list type with `a) b) c)` etc. So now you only have to rebuild the output and css in the ck editor for that.

```
ol {
  counter-reset: list;
}
ol > li {
  list-style: none;
}
ol > li:before {
  content: counter(list, lower-alpha) ") ";
  counter-increment: list;
}
```

In our case we use an additional "trick" to get there. Just replace `ol[style="list-style-type:lower-alpha"]` with the `ol` above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.{{yourinstance}}.inserthtml('htmlcode')
```

to insert html, you need to do this on ckeditor.instanceready, you only need to send the html code for what you want.

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml('<ol type="A"><li>itema</li><li>itemb</li><li>itemc</li></ol>')
```

with this you can create a plugin if you want it in a button

Note: My example outputs A. item if you really need a) item you need to do it on html and css